# On radio button click change the label of a form element in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dom, project

I want to on radio button click change label text and text is in javascript object and in object there label array in that 3 label in three language marathi hindi english and i want change the text of labels of form element with respected language like when i click on radio button hindi label of a form element are change in hindi language and text in json format read from api and convert it into object in that object their is array of label for each element

Comment: Could you please remove all the code not directly related to your question from your snippet? Your snippet is too big for such question.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, but now, unfortunately, it has no code at all :( But answering broadly, you can add an even listener to your radiobutton group, and when the value changes, you can do an AJAX request to fetch new text, and then use the response to update your form labels. You can also cache the responses (i.e. save them in an array or an object on the client) to avoid doing too many requests.

Comment: Can you please explain with one example I can understand better